# Rails 5.2 exceptions not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I upgraded from 5.1 to 5.2 and now my exceptions are not showing, and I'm seeing the 500 error page, as if I had `config.consider_all_requests_local` set to false... it's set to `true` in my `development.rb` however.

Also, as a sidenote, when the exception happens theres *literally* **10 seconds** of log output in the terminal before rails responds. It's so much log output that I can't even scroll to see if the error is being triggered by something else.

Comment: without a stack trace I'm not sure how to help?

Comment: When I scroll to the top of the 10 seconds of output, it's the normal exception of whatever I break to test it (for instance, forcing an image filename to be wrong). The problem isnt the exception itself, its that there is no exception showing... I see the rails 500 error page that normally shows in production (public/500.html)

Comment: dit you check for application.rb for exception config?

Comment: I manually copied and replaced every file from a fresh rails 5.2 app, so nothing is different from the default from what i can see

Comment: I submitted an issue for this in rails repo https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32578

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To all the people that find this... here is the problem. I had to remove the `web-console` gem from the gemfile (leftover from previous Rails versions), and it works now.

```
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!  I had this same issue and was pulling my hair out for the last 2 hours trying to figure out what i was doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your Gemfile with gem 'web-console' and remove version.
Run `bundle install'

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an issue with the remotipart and web-console gems. I was able to downgrade remotipart and all is well.

> gem 'remotipart', '1.3.0'

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32578